# How to update note on Facebook using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

My website can post a note or a feed into Facebook and receive noteid or feedid.
And now, I need to update a note or feed but i don't know how to do that.
Please help me!!! (^~^)

Answer (score 0):

A [Quick Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=Facebook+API+Update+Note) Found the [Notes API Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notes) and led me right to [Note Editing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notes.edit).

Comment: Oh! Thanks for your answer. But it is old REST API. Now there is new GRAPH API. And I use Facebook C# SDK to support my website connect and work with Facebook. So I'm finding a solution use Facebook C# SDK to solve my problem. Thanks you very much. Any idea more for me

Comment: I [don't see a way](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) of editing through the new Graph API. Maybe cache the note locally then provide a final "Publish" feature in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want edit note with Graph API, you need send POST request:
https://graph.facebook.com/{NOTE_ID} with **both** fields: *subject* and *message*.
If you send only with one param, another in note set as empty